# Capistrano/rails doesn't work with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy Rails app with capistrano. It's Rails 5.1 based.
Ruby version is managed by rvm.
I am using ruby 2.2.3, created gemset manually.
Here is deploy.rb

```
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.3@cardlove-api'
...
with RAILS_ENV: fetch(:environment) do
  execute :rake, "webpacker:install"
end
```

So, it seems worked when Rails < 5.0. But when Rails > 5.0, webpack should be installed by this command:

`bundle exec rails webpacker:install` 
(instead of bundle rake)

```
with RAILS_ENV: fetch(:environment) do
  execute :rails, "webpacker:install"
end
```

But it doesn't work for me. I've installed bundle in the gemset I am using, but getting error:

```
01 bundle exec rails webpacker:install
01 bash: bundle: command not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@IP: rails 
  exit status: 127
  rails stdout: Nothing written
  rails stderr: bash: bundle: command not found
```

Of course, I included capistrano/rails in my capfile.

```
capistrano/rvm
capistrano/rails
```

I am not sure why I am getting error. I think I configured correctly , but...
Anyway, Would you like to help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Why create gemsets anymore?  Doesn't bundler remove the need for this altogether now?

Comment: bkunzi01 - I am not sure what you mean. bundler is installed inside gemset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [capistrano/bundler](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I redefined task and getting another error.

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as cardeploy@172.104.171.129: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
Any idea why?

Comment: Mind explaining Your answer otherwise this is better as a comment since it is essentially just a link